# T-SQL Xquery Exist Method return nothing

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have the following xquery piece, I'm trying to test outside of my t-sql script:

```
    DECLARE @x XML

    SELECT @x = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Root xmlns="http://www.w3.org">
        <Header>
            <Record>
                <A99>
                    <A99_01_0>
                        <A99_01>TEST</A99_01>
                        <A99_02>TEST</A99_02>
                        <A99_03>TEST</A99_03>
                    </A99_01_0>
                </A99>
            </Record>
        </Header>
    </Root>
    '; 

select @x.exist('//Header/Record/A99/A99_01_0/A99_01')
```

I simply want to check if there is a value between the A99_01 tags, which there is.  But according to my exist(), my output keeps coming back as 0, indicating that it doesn't exist.

Is there something I'm missing?  I've double checked to make sure my syntax for the exist() is correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you're missing the **XML namespace** defined in your XML document!

```
SELECT @x = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
              <Root xmlns="http://www.w3.org">
                    *************************
```

You need to change your `SELECT` to:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org')
  SELECT 
      @x.exist('//Header/Record/A99/A99_01_0/A99_01')
```